# Different style when different classes were added

Tags: html, css

I've got this code

```
<div class="main first">
   <div class="content">
        <!--HERE IS SOME CODE-->
   </div>
</div>
```

I've got a `div` which has the class `main`. This div has a second class, which is dynamicly added, when some conditions match. So the second class can be class `first` or `second`. There is also another `div` with the class `content` within the main `div`. When the class `first` is added, the class `content` should have a different style as when the class `second` is added.

So I tried something like this:

```
.main.first.content {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.main.second.content {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

So the class `content` should have `margin-top: 10px;` when class `first` was added and `margin-bottom: 10px;` when class `second` was added. But this didn't work. How can I do this. I hope it's clear enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `.main.first.content` to `.main.first .content`

`.main.first.content` means and element that has all the 3 classes where as `.main.first .content` translates to an element with class `content` that is a descendent of an element that have the classes `.main` and `.first`

Comment: Hi.. Perfect, this works fine for me, thanks a lot! I will accept it as correct as soon as possible. Cheers. :)